# Creditor badge not received on upvoted answer

Tags: discussion, documentation, badges

I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604692/please-explain-why-php-switch-case-is-always-executing-case-0-in-this-code/41604945#41604945) yesterday which cites two examples – one I've contributed to and one I haven't. Despite three upvotes, I have not received the creditor badge. I know these things are often triggered by a periodic script run, but not sure how often that happens. Is there anything wrong here? And is there a way to see when scripts are scheduled to be run, or last run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the answer being upvoted, at least one of the examples needs to be upvoted in order to earn a badge. Generally, there are quality checks for badges that aren't spelled out in the description because of limited space. (See, for instance, the [Curious badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234959/1438).) If the example you edited gets an upvote, you'll earn [Bluebook](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5850/bluebook). When an example you *haven't* edited is upvoted, the [Creditor](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor) badge can be credited to you.